# Drupal 8 cache can't be disabled for development

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-8

Despite I followed all steps in this article, I still need to clear the cache manually in Drupal *(config/development/performance)*: https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

I followed the steps under the heading **Enable local development settings**

I use MAMP and disabled the cache in the MAMP settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `sites/development.services.yml` file. The `parameters:` was defined twice. The file should be look like this:

```
# Local development services.
#
# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your development.services.yml under 'services':

```
cache.backend.memory:
class: Drupal\Core\Cache\MemoryBackendFactory
```

and add these lines to your settings.local.php:

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['gzip'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['gzip'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['response']['gzip'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I only see the changes after caching manually in Drupal. My development.services.yml file looks like this right now: 
'parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
  cache.backend.memory:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\MemoryBackendFactory
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false'

Comment: Are you sure the settings.local.php is included correctly? Try to place a die; or something in the file for testing purposes.